# Meaning D-H-Dek in plays' catalogues?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

I've found several entries within catalogues of plays which feature the format **D - H - Dek**, but I haven't been able to determine the letters' meaning.

example (from http://www.jussenhoven-fischer.de/katalogs/titel/D)

> Lotte Ingrisch / Die Kybernetische Braut / Eine Weltenkomödie in 5 Aufzügen / **5 D, 4 H, 2 Dek**

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stands for the cast and the need of decoration in the play:

- D = Damen (Women)
- H = Herren (Men)
- K = Kinder (Children)

and

- Dek = Dekoration (decoration)

For example, the code for »Damen mit Lift« is:

> 4 D, 1 H, 1 K, 1 Dek

This means:
To perform this play, you need four women, one man, one child and one decoration

Comment: What is a decoration in this context?

Comment: @CarstenS: Irgend ein Ding, das auf einer völlig leeren Bühne nicht vorhanden ist, ohne das man das Theaterstück aber nicht spielen kann. Z.B. kann ich mir vorstellen, dass man das Stück »Damen mit Lift« nur unzureichend spielen kann, wenn man auf der Bühne keinen Lift hat.

Comment: Danke. Das habe ich mir so in etwa natürlich gedacht, ich habe mich nur gefragt, wie hilfreich hier die Anzahl ist, ohne zu wissen, was genau es ist. Ein Lift mag mehr Probleme bereiten als drei Topfpflanzen. Daher hatte ich mich gefragt, ob ich etwas übersehe.